# Get both insert_id and updated row id in insert_update query

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I have a query like this:

```
SET @uids = '';

INSERT INTO tbl1 (name,used,is_active)
VALUES (1,0,0),(2,0,0),(24,0,0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
    , used = (SELECT @uids := concat_ws(',', LAST_INSERT_ID(), @uids))
    , used = used+1
    , is_active = CASE WHEN used > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

SELECT @uids;
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to figure out the way of getting updated row id.

I get updated row ids' in `@uids` if it updates any rows but if a row is inserted, I can't get the id of that. So how to get both inserted row id and updated row id?

Or how to execute `(SELECT @uids := concat_ws(',', LAST_INSERT_ID(), @uids))` in insert before `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` ?

Comment: You would probably need to echo out the duplicate key first, meaning running 2 queries, one that will get the inserted row, and the updated row. Or.. you could also run 2 SELECT in 1 query.

Comment: May be this could be helpful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @Ctc how to run the query that get the inserted row before `ON DUPLICATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Time's short and we are long*

You can't do it, because there is no way to fill `@uids` while inserting which needs a `select` clause and you are not allowed to use a `select` clause within an `insert` statement unless your query can be transformed into an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html).

### *Long answer*

As long as you don't try to insert mixed values that may result in both updating and inserting (*which probably you do*) there is a nasty but safe way you can go with:

```
SET @uids := '';
INSERT INTO `tbl1` (name, used, is_active)
    VALUES (1,0,0),(2,0,0),(24,0,0)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        is_active = CASE WHEN used > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id),
        used = used + 1,
        id = (SELECT @uids := concat_ws(',', LAST_INSERT_ID(), @uids));
SELECT @uids, LAST_INSERT_ID() as f, MAX(id) as l from `tbl1`;
```

Being not so tricky, you have two values at the end:

1. `LAST_INSERT_ID() as f` is the first inserted row ID
2. `MAX(id) as l` which is last inserted row ID

So with that two boundaries you surly have all inserted rows IDs. Saying that it has drawbacks and that is you always have a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` value even if rows only were affected by update statement. However as you tagged your question with [php](/questions/tagged/php) there was a chance to get benefit from [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) while doing a [`multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) but I couldn't produce expected return values from `mysqli_affected_rows` as is [documented by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html):

> For `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements, the affected-rows
>   value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an
>   existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its
>   current values.

*You can try it yourself and see if it works. If you get an expected return value then you can understand if your query has done some updates or inserts and read results based on that*

As my short answer, there is no correct way to do it within the same query context but may be doing it programatically is neater? (*though I don't bet on its performance*)

```
$values = [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [24, 0, 0]];
$insertIDs = [];
$updateIDs = [];

foreach ($values as $v) {
    $insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl1` (name, used, is_active) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $insert->bind_param('ddd', $v[0], $v[1], $v[2]);
    $insert->execute();
    if ($insert->affected_rows == -1) {
        $update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `tbl1` SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), used = used + 1, is_active = CASE WHEN used > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE name = ?"); // considering `name` as a unique column
        $update->bind_param('d', $v[0]);
        $update->execute();
        if ($update->affected_rows == 1)  {
            $updateIDs[] = $update->insert_id;
        }
    } else {
        $insertIDs[] = $insert->insert_id;
    }
}

var_dump($updateIDs);
var_dump($insertIDs);
```

Example output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(140)
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(337)
}
```

One another workaround could be using MySQL [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). By creating an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on table `tbl1`, you are able to store IDs for later use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_tbl1
AFTER INSERT
    ON `tbl1` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `some_table` SET last_insert_ids = concat_ws(',', LAST_INSERT_ID(), last_insert_ids) WHERE id = 1;
END;
```

Comment: I was amazed by your creativity for the first way you suggested. Thank you.